# MarkLogic Roxy configuration for app-modules-db

Tags: marklogic, roxy

In the default.properties file in a Roxy project, what is the difference between these two settings?

```
app-modules-db=${app-name}-modules
modules-db=${app-name}-modules
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm one of the originators and current maintainers of Roxy. I vaguely remember that there was a reason we split those in the beginning, but assuming there was, I have no idea what it was. From a review of the code, they appear to be used interchangeably.

Values for both are set in deploy/default.properties. I suggest ensuring that they have the same value. You can either stick with the default, or if you need to change it, this should work:

```
app-modules-db=my-better-name
modules-db=${app-modules-db}
```

There was [a proposal to merge the two](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/issues/651) (feel free to +1 that issue to bump up its priority), and I think that's something we on the Roxy team should do. Until then, just ensure you have the same value.